# getting null in customer email Magento 2 Custmer session

Tags: magento2, blocks, email, customer-session

Edit.php (block)

```
class Edit extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $request;

    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \FM\Quick\Model\QuickFactory $modelFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request




    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
         $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

    }




    public function getIddata()
    {
        $this->request->getParams(); 
        return $this->request->getParam('id');
    }


    public function getCollection(){

        $id=$this->getIddata();
        $customer_email=$this->getCustomer();  //here i'm getting null


        $d=$this->_modelFactory->create();
        return $d->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quick_id',$id);

    }

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customerData=$this->customerSession->getCustomer();

        return $customerData->getEmail();

    }

}
```

> $customer_email=$this->getCustomer();  //here i'm getting null
>
> getting null on this variable
>
> why is not getting customer email in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Ref. https://sohel.dev/2017/05/05/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/

```
namespace SR\CustomerSession\Model\Customer;

class Context
{
    /**
     * Customer authorization cache context
     */
    const CONTEXT_CUSTOMER_ID = 'logged_in_customer_id';
}
```

> di.xml [SR/CustomerSession/etc/frontend/di.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="sr-customer-app-action-dispatchController-context-plugin" type="SR\CustomerSession\Plugin\App\Action\Context" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> create SR/CustomerSession/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php

```
namespace SR\CustomerSession\Plugin\App\Action;

use SR\CustomerSession\Model\Customer\Context as CustomerSessionContext;

class Context
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return mixed
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        if(!$customerId) {
            $customerId = 0;
        }

        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            CustomerSessionContext::CONTEXT_CUSTOMER_ID,
            $customerId,
            false
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

**Now you can able to get customer id following way even cache enable:**

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
*/
$this->httpContext->getValue(SR\CustomerSession\Model\Customer\Context::CONTEXT_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

Comment: this is right answer..

Answer (score 1):

Replace your block code with the following code:

```
class Edit extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $request;

    protected $customerSession;

    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \FM\Quick\Model\QuickFactory $modelFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager




    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
         $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
   { 
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->getCustomerSession();

        return $this;
   }


    public function getCustomerSession(){
        $customerSession = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();
        return $customerSession;     
   }

    public function getIddata()
    {
        $this->request->getParams(); 
        return $this->request->getParam('id');
    }


    public function getCollection(){

        $id=$this->getIddata();
        $customer_email=$this->getCustomer();  //here i'm getting null


        $d=$this->_modelFactory->create();
        return $d->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quick_id',$id);

    }

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customerData=$this->customerSession->getCustomer();

        return $customerData->getEmail();

    }
 }
```

Also, run compile command and delete the generated folder, hope it works

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    } 
    public function getCustomerData() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData();
            $customerEmail = $customerData->getEmail();
        }
    }
```